# How to delete directories older than one hour (cron job)

Tags: bash, cron

My application creates directories when user performs certain action. These directories are stored on my machine for exactly one hour and than are deleted.

Now I would like to move the 'deleting logic' part of application into a cron job that will run every minute.

Let's say that directories for deletion are located in `/tmp/files/`. The script should check all directories in this path and **delete all that was created one hour ago**.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

** **SOLVED** **

This will do the trick:

```
find ./* -mmin +60 -type d -exec rm -rdf {} \;
```

Comment: If you solved it yourself, please post as an answer and accept it. This prevents solved/answered questions from being bumped unnecessarily.

Comment: If you use Linux and thus GNU find, use `+` instead of `\;`. This will be faster and less resource intensive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shouldn't use `find ./*` because this causes the shell to expand the wildcard before invoking `find` which will fail if there are too many files.

Instead, you need to pass `"./*"` to the find command like this:

```
find . -type d -path "./*" -mmin +60 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```